# Storyboard gone walkabout

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

Removed a reference from a Viewcontroller and my Storyboard has evaporated instead.

Where do I find it and how do I restore it?

Have followed several links on SE and I don't see the same folder structure. 
Am on 7.2.

Comment: Are you using source control?  Just checkout the storyboard file to revert the changes since your last commit.

Comment: Using timemachine but can't see where Storyboard is located.

Comment: Found it and added it back into the project. Gather it's called main.storybaord rather than just storyboard... But now get this type of error: I'm clearly not being subtle enough.

2016-01-20 21:28:14.031 S123[376:30780] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4F0BC78A-A46D-4EF6-BDF7-5DC99D4F7B0C/S123.app> (loaded)'

*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I think you may be a victim of case the sensitive nonsense we've been plagued with since the begimnings of compilers that tried to shave off milliseconds by doing binary byte comparisons of source file characters (which none of them do now with UTF and such character coding).  There must be a place where "main" is not "Main"

Comment: When the reference was removed the setting was removed in General/Deployment Info/Main Interface - select the Main.storybaord and it will then appear as Main.